# Cannot seem to create Homegroup

Tags: windows-7, homegroup

For some reason I cannot seem to find the option to create a Homegroup after I removed it (just the join now button is available). The homegroup provider and listener services are running. Why would this be the case?

Comment: I assume this isn't Windows 7 Starter or Basic... Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, no, its now fixed (and sorry for not answering sooner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by shutting off my network connections, then creating the homegroup. It seems (though I am not sure) that the issue was that someone else on the network was trying to  start a homegroup, and I was being forced to join it.